# Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException when Decrypting RSA in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, .net-core

I'm testing RSA in C# dotnet core. I create two RSA objects, one for encrypting and the other for decrypting. I export the public key from the first rsa object and import it for the other object. When the second one decrypt the cipher array, it throws `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException`.
The code is below:

```
        String plainstr = "Hello World";

        RSA rsa1 = RSA.Create();
        RSA rsa2 = RSA.Create();
        rsa1.KeySize = 1024;
        rsa2.KeySize = 1024;

        byte[] cipherbytes = rsa1.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainstr), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        //If the parameter is true, it works well. But when I use it in an actual project, I won't pass the private key.
        RSAParameters parameters = rsa1.ExportParameters(false);
        rsa2.ImportParameters(parameters);
        //Exception is here.
        byte[] plaintbytes = rsa2.Decrypt(cipherbytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plaintbytes));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how RSA Encryption works. You can `Encrypt` with the public key but you can **only** `Decrypt` with the private key.

In your example you are encrypting the string with the private key of the `rsa1` object, you are copying the public parameters of it to `rsa2` and you are trying to decrypt with it.

Maybe you want to do the opposite?

Comment: Oh my god! I know it. But I just confused when I code，haha. Thank you!

Comment: @boyang glad that you found it! Could you mark it as the answer please?

Comment: yeah, but how to. I am new and fail to find such a button

Comment: @boyang Unter the vote down button, there's a green check you can click.